# How to pass an autocomplete list to a pipe in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

In shell we do this: `ls l`<kbd>Tab</kbd> and we get the list of files which begins on l.

The question is: in shell, how to make something like this `ls l`<kbd>Tab</kbd>`| cat` using <kbd>Tab</kbd> or not to autocomplete but not using pattern `ls l*`

Comment: what is wrong with `ls l*` in your case ?

Comment: It's just a scientific interest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really mean `shell`? I think you mean bash. :-)

Autocomplete in bash can be called manually like this:

```
compgen -C ls -f
```

Have a look for bash man page and the keywords `compgen` and `complete`

If the man pages for `compgen` and `complete` could not be found take a look for `man bash`.

Comment: What is the name of your shell. I have no prog which executable is called shell. Maybe there is some shell which is called shell. What is the output of : `echo $SHELL` from your shell?

Comment: @Klaus, I've read about it in man bash. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: doesn't work on mac… or rather… this particaular command works (sort of); but most do not